# Projection onto the Homology of an operad

Tags: operads

Suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ is a differential graded operad over a field and that $H(\mathcal{O})$ (i.e. taking the arity wise homology) is an operad, too.
(If possible, I would avoid to restrict to *symmetric* operads)

Is the natural projection $\pi : \mathcal{O} \to H(\mathcal{O})$ necessarily 
a morpism of operads?

Comment: Taking the aritywise homology always gives an operad.

Comment: Just a comment: over a field, it's true that for any chain complex $C_*$ there always exists a splitting $C_* = H_*(C) \oplus V \oplus V[1]$ where the differential sends $v \in V$ to $v \in V[1]$ (zero elsewhere), and you can use that to project $C_*$ onto $H_*(C)$. But there is no way to choose that splitting canonically, and usually no way to choose it in each arity to get a morphism of operads $\mathcal{O} \to H(\mathcal{O})$. Over a general ring, the splitting that I've mentioned doesn't even necessarily exist (and there are probably chain complexes with no projection $C_* \to H_*(C)$).

Comment: Ah ok. Good to know. Thanks! This is in particular useful since many operads are relatively simple vector spaces, arity wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any such natural projection.

Comment: What? Project first onto the kernel of the differential in homological degree $k$. This is a linear map.  Then take the quotient with the image of the differential in degree $k+1$. What is the problem with this map?

Comment: @Mark: there's no natural way to project onto the kernel of the differential.

Comment: Ah ok. I see. I would delete the question, but it's not possible anymore.